# "file has unexpected size" / "mirror sync in process" errors when running sudo apt update

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, downloads, macbook-pro

I am trying to download Ubuntu on my Macbook pro (macOS Monterey) but when I run `sudo apt update`, I get the following error:

```
file has unexpected size (13205 != 1747700. Mirror sync in process ? 
Err: 65 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu. focal-security/restricted amd64 package
```

I get lots of this error message and I am not sure what I am missing.  I have tried to download virtualbox and the ISO files but still having the same issue. I am new to Linux

Comment: Wait an hour and try again.  This is a sign that whatever repository mirror you're using is mid-sync and is not up to date yet.  This is usually a temporary issue that resolves itself in time.

Comment: @Nmath Not necessary, this is a known issue when someone's using a mirror that is mid-sync with the main Ubuntu archives.

Comment: "I am trying to download updates and start by using `sudo apt update`" "and I am getting a ton of these error messages when I run `apt update`"  No, it's pretty clear what OP is running into and trying to do.  (that's the interpretation based on the question, the command they ran, and the output displayed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt update fails at chrome stable main: "File has unexpected size (1103 != 1104). Mirror sync in progress?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147254/apt-update-fails-at-chrome-stable-main-file-has-unexpected-size-1103-1104)

Comment: After some days, I tried again to reboot but unfortunately not progress.